# Android sliding pages with blueprint about the apps?

Tags: android, android-activity, slider, destructor

I would like to develop those pages that pop up only the first time an user opens an app, where you typically see instructions on where to click to obtain some services. Those pages that can be shifted laterally and appear only once.
I though of looking up splash but it is not exactly the very same thing. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following library

[Showcase](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/RoboDemo)

[Tour Guide](https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide)

Using it you can achieve tutorial for users for your app.